# How to slice array quickly based on conditions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-slicing

I have a giant nested for loop....10 in all, but for illustration here, i am including 6. I am doing a summation (over multiple indices; the incides are not independent!). The index in any inner for loop depends on the index of the outer loop (except for one instance). The inner-most loop contains an operation where i slice an array (named 'w') based on 8 different conditions all combined using '&' and '|'. There is also this 'HB' function that takes as an argument this sliced array (named 'wrange'), performs some operations on it and returns an array of the same size.

The timescale for this slicing and the 'HB' function to execute is 300-400 microseconds and 100 microseconds respectively. I need to bring it down drastically. To nanoseconds.!!

Tried using dictionary instead of array (where i am slicing). It is much slower. Tried storing the sliced array for all possible values. That is a very huge computation in its own right since there are many many possible combinations of the conditions (these conditions depend indirectly on the indices of the for loop)

s goes from 1 to 49

t goes from -s to s

and there are 641 combinations of l,n

Here, i have posted one value of s,t and an l,n combination for illustration.

```
s = 7
t = -7 
l = 72
n = 12
Nl = Dictnorm[n,l]
Gamma_l = Dictfwhm[n,l]
Dictc1 = {}
Dictc2 = {}
Dictwrange = {}
DictH = {}
DictG = {}
product = []
startm = max(-l-t,-l)
endm = min(l-t,l)+1
sum5 = 0
for sp in range(s-2,s+3): #s'
    sum4 = 0
    for tp in range(-sp,-sp+1): #t'
        #print(tp)
        sum3 = 0
        integral = 1
        for lp in range(l-2,l+3): #l'
            sum2 = 0
            if (n,lp) in Dictknl2.keys():
                N1 = Dictnorm[n,lp]
                Gamma_1 = Dictfwhm[n,lp]
                for lpp in range(l-2,l+3): #l"
                    sum1 = 0
                    if ((sp+lpp-lp)%2 == 1 and sp>=abs(lpp-lp) and 
                        lp>=abs(sp-lpp) and lpp>=abs(sp-lp) and 
                        (n,lpp) in Dictknl2.keys()):
                        F = f(lpp,lp,sp)
                        N2 = Dictnorm[n,lpp]
                        Gamma_2 = Dictfwhm[n,lpp]
                        for m in range(startm, endm): #m
                            sum0 = 0
                            L1 = LKD(n,l,m,l,m)
                            L2 = LKD(n,l,m+t,l,m+t)
                            for mp in range(max(m+t-tp-5,m-5), 
                                            min(m+5,m+t-tp+5)+1): #m'
                                if (abs(mp)<=lp and abs(mp)<=lpp and 
                                    abs(mp+tp)<=lp and abs(mp+tp)<=lpp 
                                    and LKD(n,l,m,lp,mp)!=0 
                                    and LKD(n,l,m+t,lpp,mp+tp)!=0):
                                    c3 = Dictomega[n,lp,mp+tp]
                                    c4 = Dictomega[n,lpp,mp]
                                    wrange = np.unique(np.concatenate
                                             ((Dictwrange[m],                                  
                                             w[((w>=(c3-Gamma_1))&
                                             ((c3+Gamma_1)>=w))|
                                             ((w>=(c4-Gamma_2))& 
                                             ((c4+Gamma_2)>=w))])))
                                    factor = (sum(
                                             HB(Dictc1[n,l,m+t],
                                                Dictc2[n,l,m],Nl,
                                                Nl,Gamma_l,
                                                Gamma_l,wrange,
                                                Sigma).conjugate()
                                             *HB(c3,c4,N1,N2,Gamma_1, 
                                              Gamma_2,wrange,0)*L1*L2)
                                             *LKD(n,l,m,lp,mp)
                                             *LKD(n,l,m+t,lpp,mp+tp)                    *DictG[m]
                                             *gamma(lpp,sp,lp,tp,mp)
                                             *F)
                                    sum0 = sum0 + factor #sum over m'
                            sum1 = sum1 + sum0 #sum over m
                    sum2 = sum2 + sum1 #sum over l"
                sum3 = sum3 + sum2 #sum over l'
        sum4 = sum4 + sum3*integral #sum over t' 
    sum5 = sum5 + sum4 #sum over s'
z = (1/(sum(product)))*sum5
print(z.real,z.imag,l,n)
```

TL;DR

```
def HB(a,...f,array1): #########timesucker
    perform_some_operations_on_array1_using_a_b_c_d
    return operated_on_array1


for i in ():
    for j in ():
       ...
         ...
          for o in ():
              array1 = w[w>some_function1(i,j,..k) & 
                         w<some_function2(i,j,..k) |.....] #########timesucker
              factor = HB(a,....f,array1) * HB(g,...k,array1) * 
                       alpha*beta*gamma....
```

It takes about 30 seconds to run this whole section once. I need to bring it down to as low as possible. 1 second is the minimum target

Comment: Dictnorm? Dictfwhm? Are they in a library or is part of your code? I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sorry. This is a subsection of my code. Those are dictionaries. They are defined elsewhere. You CANNOT reproduce my code because it needs many different files to be imported

Comment: It might be a good idea to describe what this construct is meant to calculate.

Comment: i am summing some functions over multiple indices....indices which are not independent.